# Transparent strip on part of the screen

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I have some trouble with my MacBook Pro screen : on it appeared a transparent strip. It's visible from the MacBook start and I can't make it disappear.
However, I still can click on files, softwares...

I've already tried :

- Many restarts
- Safe mode
- Reset NVRAM
- Apple Diagnostics

When I plug another screen with HDMI I don't see it on 2nd screen.

[image: Photo of screen issue]

Weird thing is that this strip has disappear once after using a full screen app for some time. But today after 2 days without using it, it's now more visible and flashes when I'm on some apps (but not flashing on desktop).

Thanks !

Comment: does the screen shows after log in, also does it shows in safe mode ? did you run Apple Hardware test, did you reset the SMC and PRAM

Comment: Yes for all. Weird thing is that it has disappear by itself one day after using the Mac for some hours in a full screen app, but now after 2 days without using it, it's now more visible and flashes when I'm using chrome (but not on desktop).